# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for build-in components)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I follow this tutorial to get to know how to combine NavigationExperimental with Redux: https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-experimental-part-3-adding-tabs-28a2c57356b6#.ltz8yp73p

Unfortunately i can't get through it as I encounter below error. This relates to NavRootComponent which is a container that wraps NavigationCardStack.
[image]

Could you please help me to find error in the code below ?

```
// root.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import NavRootContainer from './containers/NavRootContainer';
const store = configureStore();

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavRootContainer />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
};
```

Whole project: https://github.com/ppiechota/sdApp

```
// NavRootContainer.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push, pop } from '../actions/navActions';
import React from 'react';
import Home from '../components/Home';
import About from '../components/About';
import { NavigationExperimental } from 'react-native';
const { NavigationCardStack } = NavigationExperimental;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    navigation: state.navReducer
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispath) => {
  return {
    pushRoute: (route) => dispatch(push(route)),
    popRoute: () => dispatch(pop())
  }
}

class NavRootContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _renderScene = (props) => {
    const { route } = props.scene;
    if (route.key === 'home') {
     return <Home _handleNavigate={this._handleNavigate.bind(this)} />
    }
    if (route.key === 'about') {
     return <About _goBack={this._handleBackAction.bind(this)} />
    }
  }

  _handleBackAction = () => {
    if (this.props.navigation.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }
    this.props.popRoute()
    return true;
  }

  _handleNavigate = (action) => {
    switch (action && action.type) {
      case 'push':
        this.props.pushRoute(action.route);
        return true;
      case 'back':
      case 'pop':
        return this._handleBackAction();
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationCardStack
        direction='vertical'
        navigationState={this.props.navigation}
        onNavigate={this._handleNavigate}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
      />
    );
  }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NavRootContainer);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the error. I should have used CardStack when destructuring, but actually i don't understand why, I thought that NavigationCardStack is the default name.

```
const {
  CardStack: NavigationCardStack
} = NavigationExperimental
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't import `Home` and `About` components

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code and run, but still the same error.

Comment: I checked it and it says the problem is on line 60, this is where NavigationCardStack is used in render method